# How do I turn a string into a specific enum type in a macro?

Tags: julia, metaprogramming

I have a module with an enum defined in it.

```
module myModule
  @enum  type A B B C D

end

type1 = myModule.A
```

Now I want to declare an instance of this enum type but I only have a string specifying which type it is. I tried the following:

```
str = "B"
type2 = eval(:(myModule.Symbol($str)))
```

But I get a warning message which I do not quite understand:

> WARNING: replacing module myModule.

and the type of `type2` is also just a `Symbol`.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the warning. Which version of Julia are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to use `getproperty`:

```
julia> module myModule
           @enum type A B C D
       end
Main.myModule

julia> str = "B";

julia> getproperty(myModule, Symbol(str))
B::type = 1
```

Alternatively, you could create your expression as a string and then parse and evaluate it:

```
julia> eval(Meta.parse(string("myModule.", str)))
B::type = 1
```

Or, the same thing, but with string interpolation instead of using the `string` function:

```
julia> eval(Meta.parse("myModule.$str"))
B::type = 1
```

Note that the syntax `myModule.Symbol(str)` is not equivalent to `myModule.B`. It looks like that syntax really just calls `Symbol(str)` in the global scope. For example, try the following:

```
julia> myModule.length([1, 2, 3])
3

julia> @code_lowered myModule.length([1, 2, 3])
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = (Base.arraylen)(a)
└──      return %1
)
```